# Getting the Error: Cannot instantiate the type java.awt.event.ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, instance, actionlistener

So I am trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game, and I am completely new to JFrames, panels, pretty much all of the GUI stuff. I hope this is not considered a duplicate because I scanned this site for hours trying to find an answer to this. It very well be because I'm new to this that there may have been an answer, but I did not understand. Anyways, the error is stated in the title, and my goal is to figure out how to detect which button is clicked, and then have an if/else statement to control what happens next, by using methods. I realize some of the imported content is not used, but I plan on them probably being used once I get further in the program. Again, I am new to swing and everything around it. Most of my knowledge is self-taught, so any help is appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.lang.Object;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Window;
    import java.awt.Frame;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;


public class ticTacToe implements ActionListener //uses action listener because of the use of buttons, so it needs to know when the buttons are clicked
{
  public static JFrame menuFrame = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
  public static JPanel board = new JPanel(), menu = new JPanel();
  public static JButton instruct = new JButton("Instructions"), pVP = new JButton("Player VS. Player"), pVC = new JButton("Player VS. Computer");

  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    menu();
  }
  public static void menu ()//the main menu of the game
  {
    menu.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//arranges the layout of the buttons on the panel

    menu.add(instruct);//adds the instruction button

    menu.add(pVP);//adds the player vs player button
    menu.add(pVC);//adds the player vs computer button

    menuFrame.add(menu);//creates the panel
    menuFrame.setSize(450, 78);
    menuFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//sets the location to the centre of the screen
    menuFrame.setVisible(true);//makes the menu visible
  }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
instruct.addActionListener(new ActionListener());
          System.out.println(actionEvent.getActionCommand());
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the line `instruct.addActionListener(new ActionListener());`

`ActionListener` is an interface that you have to implement in a subclass.

In order for this to make sense, the simplest fix would be to change that line to `instruct.addActionListener(this)`, and move it into the constructor, because your class already implements `ActionListener`. If you go with this solution, your game logic code would be moved into the `actionPerformed()` method of your `Menu()` class. Or you can make a new class to implement it, and the game logic will go in there:

```
public class TicTacToeListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // game logic here
    }
}

public class ticTacToe implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        instruct.addActionListener(new TickTacToeListener);
        System.out.println(actionEvent.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

Comment: So what would I do here? Also, is there any way I can not use "this" because I never have so I don't really know what it means..? Or do you know of an easier way to write this method? I am trying to keep it as a method but am willing to use a class. Thanks!

`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
instruct.addActionListener(new ActionListener());
          System.out.println(actionEvent.getActionCommand());
      }`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the first solution. `ActionListener`s are bound to a Swing GUI component. Every instance of `ActionListener` has its own `actionPerformed()` method that's called when an action triggers that component. And by implementing `ActionListener` in your `ticTacToe` class, you guarantee that `actionPerformed` is a part of your class. When you say `addActionlistener(this)`, you're asking the component you're adding to call the `actionPerformed()` in the current instance of the `Menu` class

Comment: Ok, so I need to change the name of my class? or can i just change `instruct.addActionListener(new ActionListener());` to `instruct.addActionListener(this);` in the method?

Comment: In order for it to run, you have to change it to the 2nd one, but it wouldn't make any sense, and you most likely won't get the results you're looking for

Comment: It would make a lot more sense if you understood what polymorphism and interfaces are. Polymorphism: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985223/java-polymorphism

interfaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389137/interfaces-and-abstract-classes-confusion-in-java-with-examples

Comment: sorry that kind of confused me... so should I change my class name?Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Consider a group working on something. If you go with the 2nd method, it would be as if the leader is assigning another person to work on a task, because the leader doesn't know how to do it. The 1st method would be the leader taking on the task himself, because he has the ability to do it

Comment: With your original, it would be as if the leader said: "We'll let the the organizer take care of it. He/she'll keep track of the game logic." But the problem is the organizer role hasn't been filled. It's only a job posting with the `actionPerformed()` requirement. And by making a new class implementing it, that class will fill that role

Comment: Okay, sorry I was thinking that was one thing, so what you are saying is I could decide to do either?

Comment: Yes you'll have to decide on one of them

Comment: okay! So if I choose the first one, does that mean all of my methods go within `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // game logic here
    }` ?

Comment: Yeah, so basically, that `actionPerformed()`, instead of adding a new `ActionListener`, it will now search for the button clicked on, changing the game state so that `x`s and `o`s are set in your grid at the proper position, and basically all the logic in your game. It's not the most elegant way to do things, but it should work for now

Comment: ok, so now all of my game content goes in there correct? sorry just want to be sure. What about my main method?

Comment: Yes, and the `main` method in most cases like this, it would just create an instance of the game. Very short. It doesn't need to be long at all

Comment: Ok awesome, thank you! I will try this, so the main just runs the method containing it all which is just the actionPerformed()

Comment: No `main()` at the state of your initial post would be fine

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I thought I would have to run the other method in main, not run main itself? I'm very thankful for your help though, because I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Which method do you mean? `menu()`? Or `actionPerformed()`? You should just keep `menu()`, so that the program creates the game object which lets the game run. You shouldn't ever need to call `actionPerformed()` because it's taken care of by the GUI

Comment: okay so will my main be within actionPerformed()? I also tried your suggestion and it produces many errors saying I need a VariableDeclaration

Comment: I'm sorry, but at this point, I think you should look into understanding what inheritance, polymorphism, and interfaces are (in that order), because those are the basics, and understanding them will make thinking about this a lot easier. GUI is a fairly tricky concept to start with, and I do understand that all this odd syntactical stuff (`this`, `implements`, `ActionListener`) is very complicated looking, as I was there myself about 3 years ago